# Reference Shared Assemblies in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, reference

How do I reference shared assemblies in visual studio 2008?

Comment: With Project + Add Reference, Browse tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that we actually had a folder in source control called "Shared Assemblies" and that was what I needed to use.